# How to execute another script node dynamically created in JSDOM?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom, jsdom

I have tried searching similar questions but none of the existing questions address this specific problem when we are using `jsdom.JSDOM()` without `jsdom.env()` and when we are dynamically creating a new `script` node within a `JSDOM` object.

Here is the code in `bar.js`.

```
console.log('bar says: hello')
```

Here is the code in `foo.js`.

```
var jsdom = require('jsdom')
var html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Foo</title></head><body><div></div></body></html>'
var window = new jsdom.JSDOM(html, { runScripts: "dangerously", resources: "usable" }).window
var script = window.document.createElement('script')
script.src = 'bar.js'
script.onload = function () { console.log('script loaded') }
window.onload = function () { console.log('window loaded') }
```

When I run this, I only get this output:

```
$ node foo.js
window loaded
```

Neither `bar.js` nor `script.onload` gets executed. How can I fix this?

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. If you want to *add* to your question, you can but you've edited it in a way that added the solution I recommended to your code, and made it look like I was suggesting that you do things you were *already* doing. As a matter of editorial policy we don't want askers to edit their questions this way.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the browser to load your `script` element, it must be part of a document.  This is true of JSDOM, and of browsers like Chrome, Firefox, etc.

You create a `script` element, but I don't see you adding it to `window.document` anywhere. (*Creating* it is not the same as *adding* it to a document.) Something as simple as `window.document.body.appendChild(script)` would do it.

JSDOM won't be able to find your script unless you tell it where it is. Since you are asking it to parse a string, the base URL that JSDOM uses is not the one you need. You can fix this by specifying a `url` that tells JSDOM what path to use for resolving relative paths. For instance:

```
var window = new jsdom.JSDOM(html, { url: "file://.", runScripts: "dangerously", resources: "usable" }).window
```

This adds `url: "file://."`. If the `bar.js` file is in the same place as your script that invokes JSDOM, it will work.

Comment: I did as you say and I get error `Error: Could not load script: "bar.js"`. Do you know why this error occurs even if `bar.js` is present?

Answer (score 0):

This might be work: jsdom version:16.4.0, nodejs version:12.6.0

```
const jsdom = require("jsdom");

var html = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Foo</title></head><body><script></script><div></div></body></html>'
var window = new jsdom.JSDOM(html, { url: "file://.", runScripts: "dangerously", resources: "usable" }).window
var script = window.document.createElement('script')
script.src = 'bar.js'
window.document.body.appendChild(script);  // <== need to append the script child
script.onload = function () { console.log('script loaded') }
window.onload = function () { console.log('window loaded') }
```